# Record webRTC stream in mp4 using kurento media server

Tags: javascript, video, webrtc, kurento

I am working on recording the video stream using WebRTC and Kurento Media server. The recording is working fine, but I am facing an issue.

The browser is storing the media in Webm format, which does not keep the metadata information. If I am recording a mobile webRTC stream in portrait mode, then the Kurento is recording that stream, but when I am playing that video, it's being played in landscape mode everywhere.

I have done some R&D on it and found the Webm does not keep the metadata information, so I have record the video in mp4 format.

I have read the documentation of the Kurento media server but didn't found anywhere that how to record the video in mp4 format.

Can anybody tell me how we can do that?

I have tried the following things
- Changed the file extension to mp4

Answer (score 0):

Please try mentioning the recorder end-point profile spec (webm, MP4, MKV)

You can post your code as well so that corrections can be suggested.

You can also follow this code https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js/blob/master/kurento-recorder/js/index.js

At line number 112 you can include profile based on the specs used in kurento-utils.js